# Ignoring the keyboard events trapped by a program

Tags: security, keyboard, keylogger

Suppose someone has installed a software that hooks keyboard events, so that when I enter a text in an input field in my webpage, that program records everything. For example, I input password on facebook.com and then that program records it so my password is stolen.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: If somebody would know this he/she would be filthy rich.

Comment: What exactly is the problem to solve? I would either rely on anti-virus/spy software or use tools like keyscramble in the hope it helps or read all I can about inner workings of the OS in question. Also this question might be more suitable for http://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: There was no need for down-voting. I just asked a question. Tell me where i'm wrong. Down-voting won't do me any good.

Comment: This was an example used in my course for Web Programming.

Comment: I didn't downvote although my impression is that the topic is too broad. It is simply not clear what your specific problem is. Why do you ask it when it was already an example in your course? What do you want to know exactly? It is just unclear.

Comment: Umm, okay, so the example is this, which is to be solved, no answer given.

> Suppose somebody installs a trap program by hooking keyboard events to steal passwords on a public computer. Hence when the user types zyx@facebbook.com, the next string entered before pressing enter or tab key is user's password. What strategy can Facebook use to protect its users from such attacks?

Comment: Is it a vague question @Trilarion?

Comment: For programming it is quite vague because it touches on a lot of topics. Also you should put it in the question not in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

The most basic solution to this would be using an on-screen or a virtual keyboard.